# Cadenas compuestas por caracteres numéricos

Tags: javascript, string

Tengo esta cadena

```
var timestamp = 20160525083000
```

entonces la quiero dividir y tratar y lo que necesito es que al final me queden dos variables

```
var1= 25-05-2016
```

y

```
var2= 08:30
```

no se si voy por buen camino pero hice algo mas o menos asi:

```
var oFecha = timestamp;
var fecha_f = oFecha(0,7);

var oHora = timestamp;
var Hora = timestamp(8,11);
```

Pero no se como ordernarlo o si lo que hice esta bien porque trato de probarlo en la consola y me dice undefined cada vez que declaro una variable :/

Comment: Puedes usar `substr()` para sacar los datos de dia, mes y año asi como hora, minutos y segundos e ir concatenandolos en un string. Algo como `var fecha = timestamp.toString().substr(6,2)+ "-"+ ....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debo aclarar que como tienes definida la variable timestamp esta no es string, por tanto para extraer las subcadenas tengo que convertirla en el código siguiente, sin embargo si fuera timestamp = '20160525083000', nos ahorariamos la línea 2 donde convierto a string la variable **timestamp**.
Tu cadena consta de 14 caracteres, los primeros 4 es el año de tu fecha por tanto substr(0,4) corresponde a esta parte, los próximos 2 son el mes, lo cual se representa con el substr(4,2), los próximos 2 es el día, es decir substr(6,2), y así sucesivamente hasta la parte de la hora y los minutos.

```
var timestamp = 20160525083000;
timestamp = timestamp.toString();
var fecha = timestamp.substr(6,2)+ "-" +
            timestamp.substr(4,2)+ "-" +
            timestamp.substr(0,4);

var hora = timestamp.substr(8,2) + ":" +
            timestamp.substr(10,2);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias aunque ese campo lo trae un odata si es string pero no esta demas asegurarse muchas gracias me sirvio tu respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Te dejo una manera de hacerlo utilizando la libreria de manejo de fechas llamada [Moments.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
var timestamp = 20160525083000;

var fecha = moment(timestamp, "YYYYMMDDhmmss");

var1 = fecha.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var2 = fecha.format('h:mm');

console.log(var1);
console.log(var2);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: oye muchas gracias aunque descarte esta opcion porque estoy trabajando con sapui5 y no se aun como cargarle las librerias para que las agarre desde mi formateador :C pero eso esta anotado a la lista de cosas por hacer. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

> Hola necesito un poco de asesoria al respecto, resulta que tengo esta
>   cadena
>
> ```
> var timestamp = 20160525083000
> ```

El valor que estas asignando a timestamp no es una cadena, es un número. Para que sea tratado como una cadena deberías hacer la asignación colocando el valor entre comillas simples o dobles, de la siguiente forma:

```
var timestamp = '20160525083000';
```

Existen varias formas para extraer subcadenas y luego usar estas para "armar" otras cadenas. A continuación te muestro dos de ellas:

1. Usar substr

```js
var timestamp = '20160525083000';

var var1 = timestamp.substr(0,4) + '-' + timestamp.substr(4,2) + '-' + timestamp.substr(6,2);
console.info(var1);

var var2 = timestamp.substr(8,2) + ':' + timestamp.substr(10,2);
console.info(var2);
```

2. Usar expresiones regulares

```js
var timestamp = '20160525083000';

var var1 = timestamp.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{6})/, '$3-$2-$1');
console.info(var1);

var var2 = timestamp.replace(/(\d{8})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$2:$3');
console.info(var2);
```

En cuanto al error, este ocurre porque JavaScript no tiene una sintaxis como `oFecha(valor1,valor2)` para variables. Esa sintaxis se podría usar para funciones, pero eso debería tratarse en otra pregunta.

Comment: @lois6b : Respuesta corregida y aumentada.

Answer (score 1):

Lo he hecho de la siguiente manera... Creando un objeto con la cantidad de caracteres que tiene cada parte de la fecha... minutos tiene `2`, año tiene `4`, y así con todas las partes.

1. Lo primero que hago es convertir el número en una cadena de caracteres (string o texto)
2. Luego creo el objeto, todas las partes tienen `2` caracteres menos el año, que tiene `4`.
3. Recorro cada parte del objeto, en el mismo orden en que yo hice el objeto y voy restando una variable llamada `posición`. Siempre resta `2`, salvo al final, que resta `4`. Esta variable no cuenta la cantidad de segundos, por lo que empieza en `-2`.
4. Al objeto le asigno el valor de cada parte de la fecha, cortando el texto en la parte seleccionada.

Por último, llamo a la función que formatea la fecha, declaro las variables `var1` y `var2` y las muestro.

```js
function formatear_fecha(timestamp)
{
  var texto=""+timestamp
  
  /* Objeto tiempo
    c es la cantidad de caracteres
    v es el valor
  */
  var t = {
    minutos:{c:2},
    horas  :{c:2},
    día    :{c:2},
    mes    :{c:2},
    año    :{c:4}
  }
  var posición = -2
  for(var i in t)
  {
    var siguiente = t[i].c
    t[i].v=texto.slice(posición-siguiente,posición)
    console.log(i,t[i].c)
    posición -= t[i].c
  }
  return [
    t.día.v+"-"+t.mes.v+"-"+t.año.v,
    t.horas.v+":"+t.minutos.v
  ]
}

var timestamp = 20160525083000

var fecha_formateada =  formatear_fecha(timestamp)
var var1 = fecha_formateada[0]
var var2 = fecha_formateada[1]

console.log("var1 es "+var1)
console.log("var2 es "+var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el string **timestamp** siempre tendrá ese formato **yyyymmddhhiiss** has un substring y almacenalo en las variables que necesitas.

> STRING.substr(Int inicio, Longitud);

```
var timestamp = 20160525083000; //numerico
timestamp = timestamp.toString(); // String

var fecha_f = timestamp.substr(6,2) + "-" + timestamp.substr(4,2) + "-" + timestamp.substr(0,4);    
var Hora = timestamp.substr(8,2)+":"+timestamp.substr(10,2);
```

Comment: ¿Cómo es que la publicaste, eliminaste y publicaste de nuevo ? XD Puedes pulsar el botón de "recuperar"

Comment: en serio se publico dos veceS? jajajaj que raro muchas gracias amigo

Comment: @NaotoAmari Si habia escrito mal el formato en la fecha, en la edición cerré el navegador y pense que no se habian guardado los cambios. Por eso se duplico, ya que es tu pregunta puedes eliminar la respuesta anterior.